# How to compile Linux Kernel 0.95 and run it with QEMU?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, qemu

I want to compile Linux Kernel 0.95 and run it with QEMU.

But I just found [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/0.95/source) (Linux Kernel 0.95 source code).

Comment: What happened? What's your question?

Comment: Find the installer CD or floppy images for an ancient 1990s distro and use them to create a VM.  Make sure you install gcc and other required compilation tools.  Boot the VM, download the kernel source archive for 0.95, extract, compile, and install it. discover the joy of LILO.